# Target specific div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a back-to-top button in my HTML in a specific div which is a slide out panel.

```
<div class='back-to-top' id='back-to-top' title='Back to top'><i class='fa fa-chevron-up' /></div>
```

the function for that back-to-top button:

```
(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
return $(window).scroll(function() {
  return $(window).scrollTop() > 200 ? $("#back-to-top").addClass("show") : $("#back-to-top").removeClass("show")
}), $("#back-to-top").click(function() {
  return $(".slide-out-panel").animate({
    scrollTop: "0"
  })
})
})
}).call(this);
```

The problem is that, the button shows up when I scroll the body first(front page) while the panel is closed, when I open the panel and scroll the back-to-top button doesn't show up.

I'm not sure how to target that specific div (the slide out panel), that when I open it and scroll in it the back-to-top button shows up.
I think, there's a problem with the *$(document)* or *return $(window)* ?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kq1nx8ew/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: Here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kq1nx8ew) @smdsgn when you open the panel and scroll the body the back-to-top shows up, but not if you scroll the panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(window).scroll(function() {` bind an event handler to the "scroll" event on your `html, body`. If you want to detect the scroll event on your panel, you need to target your panel in your scroll function. Change your JS like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
    });
    //clode the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

  $('.cd-panel-content').scroll(function() {
    if($('.cd-panel-content').scrollTop() > 200) {
      $("#back-to-top").addClass("show");
    }
    else {
      $("#back-to-top").removeClass("show");
    }
  });

  $("#back-to-top").click(function() {
    $('.cd-panel-content').animate({scrollTop: "0"});
  });

});
```